# SOAP Client doesn't finish its job or maybe doesn't return anything?

Tags: c#, winapi, soap, windows-runtime, async-await

I'm using SOAP Client in Windows RT, I'm using Windows 8.1 OS and VS 2013. Anyway, what I want to do is just a simple task which returns a some string values.

When I try to do await - async task it doesn't return anything or maybe it just simply loses itself trying to find the client. I couldn't find a problem.

I added service reference , when I look at it in Object Browser there doesn't seem a problem. I'm stuck any idea why it's happening?

Here's my code:

```
using Namespace.InfoGetter;

private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Info info = GetInfo("en-US");
    txtInfo.Text = info.Result.Value;
}

async Task<Info> GetInfo(string culture)
{
   InfoSoapClient client = new InfoSoapClient();
   Task<InfoResponse> info = client.GetInfoAsync(culture); <<<<<<<<<<<

   Info result = await info;

   return result;

}
```

When debug comes to the line (which I put <<<) `client.GetInfoAsync(culture)` doesn't return anything and the method ends there too. What to do?

Comment: What is the `GetInfoAsync` method? It doesn't appear to be on the `SoapClient` class

Comment: `Info info = GetInfo("en-US");` returns a `Task<Info>`. What exactly is the `Info.Value` property? Do you mean `Info.Result`?

Comment: yes I'm sorry I forgot. that should be `Info.Result.Value` @Yuval

Comment: That is important information. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code example isn't accurate, i assume what is happening is that you have a **deadlock**, since you block on `info.Result` while your await in `GetInfo` is trying to marshal work back to your UI thread.

We're going to add the `async` keyword to your buttons click event handler and `await` on `GetInfoAsync`

Try this:

```
private async void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Info info = await GetInfoAsync("en-US");
    textInfo.Text = info.Value
}

private Task<Info> GetInfoAsync(string culture)
{
    InfoSoapClient client = new InfoSoapClient();
    return client.GetInfoAsync(culture);
}
```

Note i added the Async suffix to your GetInfo method to follow the TAP convention and removed the `async` keyword from `GetInfoAsync` as you don't really need to generate the extra state machine as all you do is return is return the result and not do additional work with it.

Comment: I cannot try this code, at the moment. But, it seems reasonable. When I get the chance I'll try it. Thanks for your answer.